# Extract first line of CSV file in Pig

Tags: csv, apache-pig, latin

I have several CSV files and the header is always the first line in the file. What's the best way to get that line out of the CSV file as a string in Pig? Preprocessing with sed, awk etc is not an option.

I've tried loading the file with regular PigStorage and the Piggy bank CsvLoader, but its not clear to me how I can get that first line, if at all.

I'm open to writing an UDF, if that's what it takes.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get that line out of the CSV file as a string'?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not great with Java.

You are going to need a UDF. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but this UDF will take a series of CSV files and turn them into maps, where the keys are the values at the top of the file.  This should hopefully be enough of a skeleton so that you can change it into what you want.

The couple of tests I've done remotely and locally indicate that this will work.

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.LoadFunc;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

import org.apache.pig.PigException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit;

public class ExampleCSVLoader extends LoadFunc {
    protected RecordReader in = null;
    private String fieldDel = "" + '\t';
    private Map<String, String> outputMap = null;
    private TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();

    // This stores the fields that are defined in the first line of the file
    private ArrayList<Object> topfields = null;

    public ExampleCSVLoader() {}

    public ExampleCSVLoader(String delimiter) {
        this();
        this.fieldDel = delimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
        try {
            boolean notDone = in.nextKeyValue();
            if (!notDone) {
                outputMap = null;
                topfields = null;
                return null;
            }

            String value = in.getCurrentValue().toString();
            String[] values = value.split(fieldDel);
            Tuple t =  mTupleFactory.newTuple(1);

            ArrayList<Object> tf = new ArrayList<Object>();

            int pos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if (topfields == null) {
                    tf.add(values[i]);
                } else {
                    readField(values[i], pos);
                    pos = pos + 1;
                }
            }
            if (topfields == null) {
                topfields = tf;
                t = mTupleFactory.newTuple();
            } else {
                t.set(0, outputMap);
            }

            outputMap = null;
            return t;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            int errCode = 6018;
            String errMsg = "Error while reading input";
            throw new ExecException(errMsg, errCode,
                    PigException.REMOTE_ENVIRONMENT, e);
        }

    }

    // Applies foo to the appropriate value in topfields
    private void readField(String foo, int pos) {
        if (outputMap == null) {
            outputMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
        outputMap.put((String) topfields.get(pos), foo);
    }

    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() {
        return new TextInputFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit split) {
        in = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(String location, Job job)
            throws IOException {
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);
    }
}
```

Sample output loading a directory with:

```
csv1.in             csv2.in
-------            ---------
A|B|C               D|E|F
Hello|This|is       PLEASE|WORK|FOO
FOO|BAR|BING        OR|EVERYTHING|WILL
BANG|BOSH           BE|FOR|NAUGHT
```

Produces this output:

```
A: {M: map[]}
()
([D#PLEASE,E#WORK,F#FOO])
([D#OR,E#EVERYTHING,F#WILL])
([D#BE,E#FOR,F#NAUGHT])
()
([A#Hello,B#This,C#is])
([A#FOO,B#BAR,C#BING])
([A#BANG,B#BOSH])
```

The `()`s are the top lines of the file. `getNext()` requires that we return something, otherwise the file will stop being processed.  Therefore they return a null schema.

Answer (score 2):

If your CSV comply with CSV conventions of Excel 2007 you can use already available loader from Piggybank http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.java?view=markup

It has an option to skip the CSV header `SKIP_INPUT_HEADER`