# Hadoop HDInsight Developer Preview Hive Linked server

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

Hi I've got Hive a table set up on HDInsight Developer Preview from a log file with the following schema:

```
drop table iislog;

create external table iislog (
    sdate STRING,
    stime STRING, 
    cip STRING,
    csusername STRING,
    sip STRING, 
    sport INT,
    csmethod STRING,
    csuristem STRING,
    csuriquery STRING,
    scstatus INT,
    scbytes INT,
    csbytes INT,
    timetaken INT,
    csuseragent STRING,
    csreferrer STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';
```

I've set a Hive DSN and a linked server

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
 @server = 'hive-test', @srvproduct='Hive',
 @provider='MSDASQL', @datasrc='Sample Microsoft Hive DSN',
 @provstr='Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;';
```

but when I select strings (integers seem OK) I get:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "hive-test" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].sip" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "hive-test".

Does anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Are you sure your IIS logs are proper `DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '`? A missing field can cause shifts in the columns which Hive will tolerate better than ODBC. I would recommend you go over http://stackoverflow.com/a/18410013/105929

Comment: I think I may have got to the bottom of this see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2013/11/12/how-to-create-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-hdinsight-hive-using-microsoft-hive-odbc-driver.aspx You need to convert the hive string to a varchar explictly and there is a setting in the ODBC DSN about the maximum length of the string which you need to have at 8000 or less. Read the blog it explains it better :)